# Bootstrap img-responsive not scaling to parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to get some images to scale responsively in their parent container using the Bootstrap `img-responsive` class, but it's not going well.  In this scenario, I want to display between 2 and 4 images in a grid pattern on the screen, and for the images to be responsive inside of their parent div.

The problem is that the images don't shrink with the `img-container` class.

https://jsfiddle.net/fcLv3750/2/

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-inner">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gHDJC06.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gHDJC06.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="row-inner">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gHDJC06.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gHDJC06.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row-container {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 50%;
  height: auto;
}

.img-container {
  padding: 4px;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 5px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.row-inner {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 50vh;   //I want the page contents to resize based on browser window height (no scrolling)
  width: auto;
}
```

NOTE: The following will make the images become responsive, but it throws off the grid by making the `img-container` the full height of the row, which I prefer not to do. (I do not want the `img-container` height to be 100%)

https://jsfiddle.net/bm83ts0p/2/

[image]

```
.img-container {
  padding: 4px;
  height: 100%;   //changed from max-height:100%
  border: 5px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}

img{
 max-height: 100%
}
```

A) What is causing the `img-responsive` class to be ignored?
B) What can I do to make the images responsive, and the `img-container` div not be 100% height.

**EDIT**: A key feature is that the content be resized to the browser window with no scrolling, hence the `height: 50vh;` for each of the 2 rows.

**EDIT2:** Here is the desired result (which only works when the images are at max-resolution with no scaling.  Large images or smaller browser window produce the problems listed above)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted your wrapper "`row-inner`" from your code as it causes the clearfix issue. Mostly it is reason.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">


  <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gHDJC06.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gHDJC06.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>


  <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gHDJC06.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gHDJC06.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

Columns in Boostrap grid immediately follows row. e.g  `row>col` to avoid any kind of clearfix issue. Hope it helps.

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dncwdvkq/

Comment: I should have made it more clear (and I've edited my post) that a key feature is that the content resize to the viewport height. hence the `height: 50vh;` for each of the 2 rows.

Comment: Could you please attach your end result as a screenshot ?  It would be more clearer.

Comment: I've including screen shots in my question, is that what your needing?

Comment: I want to see the desired result you are trying to achieve as a screenshot. This will help me for a better understanding of your question.